# How to enable StandBy mode in iOS 17 Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, widgetkit, ios17

I'm trying to build a widget that supports StandBy mode. Is it possible to enable StandBy mode in the iOS simulator?

On device there is a menu in Settings for StandBy mode. But that menu is not present in the Simulator settings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to enable StandBy mode in Simulator:

1. Open Simulator
2. Click `Features` in MacOS menu bar while Simulator is open
3. Click `Show StandBy`